# The zeroth moment of a random variable X

Tags: probability

In the book it says:

When the mean of E(X) is finite, it is convenient to consider X^(0)=X-E(X) instead of X because its first moment is equal to zero. We shall say X^(0) is obtained from X by centering.

Perhaps I am overthinking it, but I don't understand what the zeroth moment would even mean? To my understanding, the first moment (X^(1)) is equal to E(X). But I'm confused by the part that says "because its first moment is equal to zero." Is it saying the first moment if the zeroth moment?

Comment: Isn't the $0$-th moment the *expected value* of $X^0$ and not simply $X^0$? Perhaps the exponent zero is being used on $X$ only symbolically, to define a new variable, which may just as well have been called $U$ [$U=X-E(X)$]

Comment: The passage you describe doesn't seem to mention a zeroth moment, rather a modified random variable $X^{0}$ which by construction will have mean (first moment) zero. Have I missed the point of your Question?